# How to change the style of Page Button in Master-Detail Page for UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal, master-detail

I want to style the [Page Button](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/#Overview) in UWP for a master detail page. With the help of the *Live Visual Tree* I found out that it should be the [`ContentTogglePane` button](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml#L40).

[image: Live Visual Tree]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}" >

    <Button Name="ContentTogglePane" Style="{ThemeResource PaneButton}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}"  
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ContentTogglePaneButtonVisibility}" />

    <Border Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleVisibility}">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding DetailTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

The style is defined in [this way](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml#L173):

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PaneButton">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="48" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="" />
</Style>
```

I've tried to modify the [default button style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx) and all other button changes except the `ContentTogglePane` button. I want to remove the border and change the text color on hover as well as the background.

Which style do I have to overwrite to accomplish this? Ideally, only the `ContentTogglePane` button is overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove the border and change the text color on hover as well as the background.

I think you've found the default template style of `MasterDetailControl` and `PaneButton`, then you can copy them into the `App.xaml` file of the UWP project (aka. Application resource of UWP app). Since you want to change the style when the button is on hover, we still need the default [Button styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx), copy the `<Setter Property="Template">...</Setter>` part into the style for `PaneButton`. The "on hover" behavior is controlled by `<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">` in the default button style.

All needed resources is now in application resource, we can simply modify them as we did in standard UWP app. For example:

```
<Application
    x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MasterDetailPageNavigation.UWP"
    xmlns:uwp="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CustomePaneButton">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Wheat" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Wheat" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <x:Double x:Key="TitleBarHeight">48</x:Double>

        <Style TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
            <Setter Property="ToolbarForeground" Value="{ThemeResource DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
                        <SplitView x:Name="SplitView" IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMode="Overlay">
                            <SplitView.Pane>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding MasterToolbarVisibility}"  Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}">
                                        <Button Name="PaneTogglePane"  Style="{StaticResource CustomePaneButton}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" />
                                        <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding MasterTitle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding MasterTitleVisibility}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" />
                                    </StackPanel>

                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MasterPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Master}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </SplitView.Pane>
                            <SplitView.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <uwp:FormsCommandBar x:Name="CommandBar" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleVisibility}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                                        <uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Button Name="ContentTogglePane" Style="{StaticResource CustomePaneButton}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}"  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SplitView,Path=IsPaneOpen,Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="{StaticResource TitleBarHeight}">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding DetailTitle}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                                                </ContentControl>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
                                    </uwp:FormsCommandBar>

                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DetailPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Detail}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </SplitView.Content>
                        </SplitView>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is the rendering image of this style:

[image]

Comment: You have changed the `BorderBrush`, the `Foreground` and added the `Background` in the `ControlTemplate` for `PointerOver`. What's more interesting though is, that you added `MasterDetailControl` and assigned the `PaneButton` to our new style. Where do you get the styling from `MasterDetailControl`? One more question: Why doesn't it work if I put the style for the `MasterDetailControl` into a separate XAML by using `MergedDictionaries`? I can put the button style in the separate XAML, but not for the `MasterDetailControl`.

Comment: I only found [MasterDetailControlStyle](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml), but it doesn't match the style in your answer.

Comment: @testing, oh, I forgot to mention this in my answer, since I used the stable version 2.3.2 of xamarin, I need to use the corresponding style in this version, and it is in the [Resources.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2.3.2/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml), not in a separated xaml file like it is in later version. Please notice the different branches for different xamarin version on Github.

Comment: @testing, for your second question, I just tested it, found the same issue, strange thing, I'm not sure why putting in a separated resource dictionary will make it not work by now, sorry.